# emacs で、 Mode Line の行表示が、たまに L?? になる

Tags: emacs

再現条件はよくわかっていないのですが、 modeline (major モードとかが表示されているあの行) で、表示している行の表示 (L23 とか普段は表示されている)が、たまに L?? になるときがあります。

とくに、 tramp したりしていると、これが再現する場合が多くなるように思います。

1. 何が原因でしょうか
2. 発生した場合の、対処方法などありますでしょうか。

Comment: 原因の一つとして考えられるのは `line-number-display-limit-width` 変数の設定値でしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントにもありますが
`line-number-mode` は `line-number-display-limit-width` 変数の設定値 (初期値 200) より
「１行の長さが長い」行があると `L??` 表示になってしまいます。
`emacs` は行数が多いのは平気なのですが、１行が長いのは苦手、なためらしいです。

```
(set-variable 'line-number-display-limit-width 1000)
```

とかで解決すると思われます。